# How to set Day Start for events in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, fullcalendar

I would like to change the start day to 10:00?

When I move the event out by a day in the next day, it starts not from 00:00 but from 10:00. This is shown in the screenshot below.

I used:

- `minTime` and `maxTime` attribute but it only hides hours - the event
  is out of 10:00 - 18:00,
- eventConstraint:"businessHours"; - I can put events only between
  10:00 - 18:00  but I am not able to move/resize it out of that time -
  it is blocked.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atlxE.png)

```
    minTime: "10:00:00",
            maxTime: "18:00:00",
        businessHours: // specify an array instead
        {
            dow: [ 1, 2, 3,4,5 ], // Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday
            start: '10:00', // 8am
            end: '18:00' // 6pm
        },
```

Comment: Where is some code?

Comment: Here it is, but this build-in functions don't helps me a lot.